# psql passing parameter to sql script

Tags: postgresql, psql

psql version 9.2, server version 12.0.

Trying to pass parameter to sql script ,
Executing the script and passing parameter :

```
psql --echo-queries -v ON_ERROR_STOP=0 -v TEST=100 postgresql://${curr_connection}<< EOF 1 > ${log_file} 2>&1
\timing
\i sql_script.sql
EOF
```

Please note I confirm script is working with no issue when using hardcoded value(without the parameter) ,
I guess it may relate that the parameter inside a quote or somthing,

sql_script.sql

```
INSERT INTO ACT_HI_COMMENT (action_,full_msg_,id_,message_,proc_inst_id_,task_id_,time_,type_,user_id_)
SELECT * FROM DBLINK ('host= MYHOST user=MYUSER password = MYPASS dbname=MYDB port=6432',
'SELECT ACT_HI_COMMENT.message_,ACT_HI_COMMENT.proc_inst_id_ FROM ACT_HI_COMMENT 
where ACT_HI_COMMENT.TASK_ID_ in (Select distinct CBAN_A.TASK_ID_ from CBAN_OSS_ACT_RU_VARIABLE_TASK 
where CBAN_OSS_ACT_RU_VARIABLE_TASK.GROUP_ID = :TEST )')
 AS LINKTABLE (proc_inst_id_ character varying,task_id_ character varying,time_ timestamp without time zone,type_ character varying,
user_id_ character varying);
```

Getting error:

```
psql:/infadmin/inf/sql_script.sql:2: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
CONTEXT: while executing query on unnamed dblink connection
```

I tried also a single quotes around it as :'TEST'

```
INSERT INTO ACT_HI_COMMENT (action_,full_msg_,id_,message_,proc_inst_id_,task_id_,time_,type_,user_id_)
SELECT * FROM DBLINK ('host= MYHOST user=MYUSER password = MYPASS dbname=MYDB port=6432',
'SELECT ACT_HI_COMMENT.message_,ACT_HI_COMMENT.proc_inst_id_ FROM ACT_HI_COMMENT 
where ACT_HI_COMMENT.TASK_ID_ in
 (Select distinct CBAN_A.TASK_ID_ from CBAN_OSS_ACT_RU_VARIABLE_TASK
 where CBAN_OSS_ACT_RU_VARIABLE_TASK.GROUP_ID = :'TEST' )') 
AS LINKTABLE (proc_inst_id_ character varying,task_id_ character varying,time_ timestamp without time zone,type_ character varying,user_id_ character varying);
```

Getting error:

```
psql:/infadmin/inf/sql_script.sql:2: ERROR: syntax error at or near "TEST"
LINE 2: ... where CBAN_OSS_ACT_RU_VARIABLE_TASK.GROUP_ID = :'TEST' ..
```

Answer (score 0):

As suspect , it didnt worked as the parameter is inside the single quotes,
I solved it by spliting the whole string inside the quotes into 2 ,
by

```
' first_part '|| :'TEST'||'  <second_part>'
```

So sql looks like

```
INSERT INTO ACT_HI_COMMENT (action_,full_msg_,id_,message_,proc_inst_id_,task_id_,time_,type_,user_id_)
SELECT * FROM DBLINK ('host= MYHOST user=MYUSER password = MYPASS dbname=MYDB port=6432',
'SELECT ACT_HI_COMMENT.message_,ACT_HI_COMMENT.proc_inst_id_ FROM ACT_HI_COMMENT 
where ACT_HI_COMMENT.TASK_ID_ in
 (Select distinct CBAN_A.TASK_ID_ from CBAN_OSS_ACT_RU_VARIABLE_TASK
 where CBAN_OSS_ACT_RU_VARIABLE_TASK.GROUP_ID = '|| :'TEST'||' )')
AS LINKTABLE (proc_inst_id_ character varying,task_id_ character varying,time_ timestamp without time zone,type_ character varying,user_id_ character varying);


``
```